# jQuery Google Maps get address based on click

Tags: jquery

I am building a Google Maps feature. When the user clicks the button the jquery script should grab the address from the textbox but its not working properly. Does anybody know what all I am doing wrong?

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&amp;language=en"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?=base_url()?>data/gmap3.js"></script>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        function getAddress() {
            $("#addressClick").click(function() {
                $('#address').val();
            });
        }
        $("#my_map").gmap3({
            marker: {
                address: getAddress()
            }, map:{
                options:{
                    zoom: 14
                }
            }
        });
    });
</script>
<input id="address" type="text" placeholder="Please type in your address"><input type="button" value="Go to location" id="addressClick">
<div id="my_map" style=" height: 350px; width: 300px;"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you don't want to load the map until the button is clicked. But, you are loading the map as soon as the page is ready.  And you are passing `undefined` as the address:

```
address: getAddress()
```

The function `getAddress()` has no return value, so when you assign it's value to a property, the property has the value of `undefined`.  All `getAddress()` does is assign a click handler to your button.  Inside the click handler, the value of the text box is read, but that value is ignored.

If you want to load the map after the button is clicked, you need to move the code to load the map inside the click handler.  Also, move that click handler binding outside of the `getAddress()` function.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#addressClick").click(function() {
        $("#my_map").gmap3({
            marker: {
                address: $('#address').val()
            }, map:{
                options:{
                    zoom: 14
                }
            }
        });
    });
});
```

**Working demo:** [jsfiddle.net/wFxDR](http://jsfiddle.net/wFxDR/)

Comment: Oh wow, I can't believe I messed that up lol. Also my Html was kind of wacky too. Thanks for your help. It works like a charm now

Comment: jsfiddle.net/wFxDR link broken